# jQuery - подставить в select значение из input - как?

Tags: jquery, input, select, onchange

Пытаюсь сделать такую штуку:

Есть input, с значением, которое пишется ручками:

```
<label for="billing_city" class="">Город</label>
<input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_city" id="billing_city" value="Красноярск" >
```

При этом, есть select, где нужно выбирать значение ручками:

```
<label for="billing_state" class="">Область/регион&nbsp;<span class="optional">( необязательно)</span></label>
<select name="billing_state" id="billing_state" class="state_select select2-hidden-accessible" data-placeholder="Выберите параметр…" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="">Выберите параметр…</option>
<option value="МОСКВА"> Москва</option>
<option value="КРАСНОЯРСК"> Красноярск</option>
```

Делаю скрипт, для подставления значений из input в select

```
<script>
$('#billing_city').on('input',function(){
    var text = $("#billing_city").val();
    $("#billing_state").val(text());
});
</script>
```

Или так:

```
<script>
$('#billing_city').on('input', function() {
  var val = this.value;
  // Getiing option based on input value and setting it as selected
  $('#billing_state option:contains(' + this.value + ')').sort(function(a, b) {
    var a1 = $(a).text(),
    a2 = $(b).text();
    console.log(a1.indexOf(val),a2.indexOf(val));
    if (a1.indexOf(val) > a2.indexOf(val))
      return 1;
    else if (a1.indexOf(val) < a2.indexOf(val))
      return -1;
    if (a1.length > a2.length)
      return 1;
    else if (a1.length > a2.length)
      return -1;
    return 0;
  }).eq(0).prop('selected', true);
});
</script>
```

Но что-то не работает каменный цветок, подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: `$("#billing_state").val(text());` text это переменная на строку выше, зачем вы скобки добавили?

Comment: видимо вы пытаетесь сделать поиск с выпадающим списком. Возможно заинтересует datalist https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist